# App's screen goes away while being used

Tags: applications, screen

Whatever I'm doing on my MacBook Pro (10.14.6) after a little while the App window slides to the left, leaving me with just the desktop screen.  It happens on any App I use including when I am watching something on Netflix or working on an Excel spreadsheet. It isn't going to sleep. No external monitors connected.  When I click on the edge of the window it comes back.  I have tried checking all of the preferences suggested for sleeping, but it isn't going to sleep and they are all set fine.  What goofy setting am I missing?  Is my Mac telling me I am working too hard? It happens whether I am plugged in or not.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Do you have any other open apps? macOS apps can remain open even though they do not have any open windows left. Open apps are represented by a black dot below their icon on the dock. IIRC apps can bring focus to themselves, which would make macOS switch from your fullscreen view to their respective desktops, but then show nothing because the app that asked for focus doesn't have windows open.

Comment: Did you receive any notifications when the screen was moved? Did any app show up on the menu bar (the top bar where the clock is located), blink, or called for attention in any way? Was there any app jumping on the dock before leaving fullscreen? Did you hear any noise?

Comment: Nope - nothing - it just slides away.  Not even close to the laptop when it happens while watching Netflix. No noise, no App looking for attention, It isn't switching to a different app, it's just going back to my desktop.